# Having a service worker installed hides server response delays

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

It looks like Firefox’s DevTools, both the Network tab and profiler, don’t show the server response time when there is a Service Worker involved. Everything is shown at 0ms. Is that expected and is there any way around it?

[image: Screenshot of the Network tab in Firefox DevTools, showing that all times in the timeline column are shown at 0ms, and that all requests have transited via the service worker.]